# Read and write on a local serial device from Django based web application hosted on a AWS linux machine.

Tags: python, django, linux, serial-port, socat

I have a local linux machine that interacts with our product locally over serial ports for communication, now i'm stuck at making an Django web application that is running on our AWS linux machine and can make direct communication to the local machine's serial port (for reading as well as writing) whenever the Django web application is accessed on that local machine.

**Things i've tried before posting :**

- Ive tried socat and netcat, for accessing the serial device over the same local network( LAN )
- Tried to forward all the data recived on the /dev/ttyS0 to 35.154.21.234 (Public IP) this ip's port number 1234 : `nc 35.154.20.239 1234 < /dev/ttyS0`
- Tried to start continuous listening on the 1234 port and forward it to the virtual port /dev/pts/2 loacted on the : `sudo nc -lvp 1234 > /dev/pts/2`

I want to use serial port of local linux machine as a serial port of my cloud hosted linux server.

**Does anyone has any idea about what i am doing wrong or how to make it possible??**

Comment: This does not sound like a great system architecture for accessing a hardware device. You will need a client program on the local machine.

Comment: How did you use socat? If I'm understanding, what you're trying to do is to bind a port in your AWS with a serial port in your local machine, is that correct?

Comment: Yes I achieved it using a machine on digital ocean but I am struggling to make it possible using aws Linux machine.